# TitleAreaDilaog - Title Area / SWT

Tags: java, jface

Is there ways to modify the appearance of the title area.  Can you add some like a horizontal line to the bottom, to better separate the title area from the rest of the dialog.   If I wanted to add a image or place text other than the standard

```
public void create() {
  super.create();
  setTitle("The Base Dialog Class");
  setMessage("Hello World");
}
```

Is it possible the make the title area look they you like and not the standard way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the title area image by using [`setTitleAreaImage(Image image)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/TitleAreaDialog.html#setTitleImage%28org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image%29) and the color by using [`setTitleAreaColor(RGB color)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/TitleAreaDialog.html#setTitleAreaColor%28org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB%29).

Moreover, you can provide feedback to the user by [`setErrorMessage(String message)`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/dialogs/TitleAreaDialog.html#setErrorMessage%28java.lang.String%29).

AFAIK, there is not much more you can do...